# Can any subset of $\mathbb R^2$ can be expressed by equations /inqualities?

Tags: set-theory, systems-of-equations

For example the set of all points on a circle in $\mathbb R^2$ can be expressed by an equation. Similarly square, rectangle, parabola, interior of a circle, triangular regions, etc.

Likewise, can any subset of $\mathbb R^2$ can be expressed by a system (finite or infinite number) of equations or by inequalities ?

Comment: Since you say you allow an _infinite_ number of inequalities, would you accept a description of the form $$ \{ x \mid (x-a)^2>0 \land (x-b)^2>0 \land (x-c)^2> 0 \land \cdots \} $$ where $a,b,c,\ldots$ are all the points that are _not_ in your desired set? (Even if there are uncountably many of them?)

Comment: @Henning Makholm  if $x, a , b, c, \ldots \in \mathbb R^2$, then how to find $(x-a)^2, (x-b)^2, (x-c)^2, \ldots$ ?

Comment: x @Fractal: For vectors we could say $(\left< x_1,x_2\right>-\left<a_1,a_2\right>)^2 = (x_1-a_1)^2 + (x_2-a_2)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Take the indicator function of the subset = 1. Then, the subset is the set of points such that that equation is true.

Comment: Is it the only way ?

Comment: This answers the question as written, but it may be worth noting that it becomes circular if "*expressed*" is replaced with "*defined*" in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow uncountably many formulas, then as Henning Makholm points out, it can be done. If you only allow finite many formulas (or equivalently, a single formula by concatenating all of them), then, interpreting your question as

> "Can every subset of $\mathbb R^2$ be defined by a formula in which you allow reals as parameters?

then it is one of those 'typical' set-theoretic questions which can't be answered using our axioms of set theory¹. We cannot prove that there exists such an "undefinable" set, and we cannot prove that no such set exists¹.

*¹ This is strictly speaking not correct, as it relies on the consistency of so-called measurable cardinals, which again cannot be proven. However, it seems to me that the majority of set theorists believe this to be true.*

Comment: The approximate distance between this answer, the question, and the OP is that measurable cardinal that you mentioned...

Comment: Yeah, this is why I shouldn't answer questions late at night..

Comment: Should be more appropriate now.